# Is there any app for lubuntu which has ability to remotely turn on the PC and use it and then tun it off also

Tags: lubuntu, remote

Is there any app for lubuntu which has ability to remotely turn on the PC and use it and then tun it off also. I want it as my computer is in NewYork and I want to access some files in my office at Canada. then how can i remotely tun on that pc and download some files. (the pc is always plugged in to mains but not turned on as it will waste electricity)

Comment: Errr... Unless you have something physically pressing the on button, how can you turn it on? You can turn it off though - wait a second.

Comment: Will you be accessing it from another Ubuntu machine, or will it be Windows or something?

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/297198/remotely-turning-on-computer

Answer (score 3):

> **[Wake-on-LAN (WOL)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan)** is an Ethernet computer networking standard that allows a shut-down computer to be turned on remotely. Most recent motherboards that have an integrated Ethernet controller that supports this feature. You can enable the Wake-on-LAN feature in the Power Management section of the motherboard’s BIOS. There are two ways of how Wake-on-LAN can work. The first one is you want to turn on a computer on the same local area network and the second one is you want to turn on a computer in another location through the internet.
>
> This is how Wake-on-LAN works; the target computer is shut down with enough power reserved for the network card to function. The network card listens for a specific packet called the “Magic Packet”. The listening computer receives this packet, checks it for the correct information, and then boots if the Magic Packet is valid. A magic packet is data consisting of “FF FF FF FF FF FF” followed by 16 repetitions of the listening network device’s MAC address.

---

**Setting Up Wake-on-LAN**

In order to use WoL it must be supported and enabled as necessary in the BIOS, NIC and other network hardware (routers, switches etc). You may also need to configure some software if things don't work out-of-the-box.

**Enabling WoL in the BIOS**

This section may differ depending on whether or not you have a NIC integrated into your motherboard.

**Using an Integrated NIC**

To enable WoL in the BIOS, enter the BIOS setup and look for something called "Wake up on PCI event", "Wake up on LAN" or similar. Change it so that it is enabled. Save your settings and reboot.

**Using a Non-Integrated NIC**

If your NIC is not integrated into your motherboard, you will still have to configure your BIOS to allow devices to wake up your computer. Boot your computer and enter the BIOS settings menu. In one of the sub-menus there will hopefully be the option to allow USB and/or PCI devices to wake-up the computer. Enable the setting that is appropriate for your NIC. Save your settings and reboot.

PCI NICs sometimes require a cable connection to the power supply in order to stay awake when the computer is off/asleep. Check your manual to see if yours does and install if necessary

**Enabling WoL in the NIC**

First, determine which NIC will be used, and then check whether it supports the Magic Packet™ using

```
sudo ethtool <NIC>
```

where  is the device name of your NIC, e.g. eth0. This command will output some information about your the capabilities of your NIC. If this output contains a line similar to the following:

```
Supports Wake-on: <letters>
```

where  contains the letter g, the NIC should support the WoL Magic Packet™ method (for the other letters look at man ethtool).

**Enabling WoL in the NIC**

To check whether WoL is enabled in the NIC, one could use

```
sudo ethtool <NIC>
```

and look for

```
Wake-on: <letters>
```

If  contains g and not d, then Magic Packet™ is enabled. However, if  does contain d, WoL needs to be enabled by running the following command:

```
sudo ethtool -s <NIC> wol g
```

On most systems, issuing this command is required after each boot. If the system's networking is configured via ifupdown, then it is easy to add the line up ethtool -s  wol g below the interface's configuration stanza in /etc/network/interfaces. For example:

```
shahar@shahar-backup:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
# The loopback network interface

auto lo iface lo inet loopback
# The primary network interface

auto eth0 iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.0.0.138
        up ethtool -s eth0 wol g
```

This will ensure that WoL is enabled in the NIC on each boot. Fore more information see the interfaces manual.

Sources [blog from raymond.cc](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-remotely-turn-on-computer-from-lan-and-wan/) & [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan)

---

**Tools** to help set this up, configure and/or use:

- [etherwake](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/etherwake) (command line)
- [wakeonlan](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wakeonlan) (command line)
- [powernap](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/powernap) (command line)
- [gwakeonlan](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwakeonlan) (gui)

**gWakeOnLan**

Installation: `sudo apt-get install gwakeonlan` or click this button

[image: Install via the software center]

[image]

[image]

Images from [ubuntugeek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/gwakeonlan-turn-the-machines-on-through-the-wake-on-lan-system.html) and that site also has a summary:

Requirements to allow gWakeOnLan to turn on a machine all these requirements must be met.
Each machine to turn on must:

- have an integrated (or PCI/PCIE) Ethernet network card.
- have the network cable plugged all the time.
- have the power cable plugged all the time.
- support the Wake On LAN with the Magic Packet.
- have the Wake On LAN enabled in the BIOS.
- have the Wake On LAN by Magic Packet enabled in the Operating System.
- be powered off from the Operating System.

If one or more of these requirements is not met all the time, the Wake On LAN will not work.

Comment: I forgot about Wake On LAN ....

Comment: @wilf you did you did! :+)

Comment: no, i don thave network cable plugged everytime, any other way?

Answer (score 0):

First install an ssh server on the remote machine you want to access:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

You will also need to install a program to download stuff, if it is not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install wget
```

Get another machine on the same network, running Ubuntu, and try `ssh`ing into the remote machine

```
ssh USERNAME@IP_ADDRESS
```

<sub>You can also 'ssh' from Windows, Mac etc, but you can find out how to do that of the internet - sorry.</sub>

The `USERNAME` entry is your username on that computer - you should see it when you open terminal, before the `@`. 
The IP address you need to use now is your local IP on that machine - see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392207/command-to-know-my-external-ip-address/392213#392213) on that.

If it works, you may want to run a test download. First change the terminal so it is in the `~/Downloads directory, so anything downloaded will end up in that folder.

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Then you can try downloading this image:
[image]

```
 wget https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD3Xo.png
```

You can then shut it down by using:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

To copy files from that computer to another, use the test machine to try this again, in nearly exactly the same way as with the ssh command earlier, and will be tested with the file downloaded via `wget`:

```
scp USERNAME@IP_ADDRESS:/home/USERNAME/Downloads/cD3Xo.png helloworld.png
```

This will copy the file through `ssh` to `helloworld` on the test machine.

---

After you have tested it on the local netowrk, you then need to access it from outside it. First [set up port forwarding on your router](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router) . This means that any request sent to the router will be diverted to your machine. Get it to be sent to the local IP address of that machine, allow SSH, etc.

After that, run this to find the external IP of your network:

```
wget http://smart-ip.net/myip -O - -q ; echo
```

Then you can test it. For this you need a machine **outside** your local network, for example an Android phone with [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot) on it. You can use it as explained earlier, but this time with the external IP address.