# Get ip of system in local network

Tags: networking

How can I find the IP of my Ubuntu System in local network‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌?

Comment: See also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/392207/178596) for the external IP address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**METHOD 1:**
Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following:

```
ifconfig
```

You get an output like this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:84:3c:e7:0f:5a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1611838 (1.6 MB)  TX bytes:1611838 (1.6 MB)

mon0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr CC-AF-78-B3-E5-0F-3A-30-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP BROADCAST NOTRAILERS RUNNING PROMISC ALLMULTI  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:877993 errors:0 dropped:115 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:533724526 (533.7 MB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr cc:af:78:b3:e5:0f  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ceaf:78ff:feb3:e50f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:377839 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:353884 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:460380208 (460.3 MB)  TX bytes:35093507 (35.0 MB)
```

As mine is wireless I can see my ip address in `wlan0` . If your is a wired connection you can see it in `eth0` or `pppo` if yours is a pppoe connection.

**METHOD 2**:
In the top panel of Unity go to the Network Icon (Network Manager) and select Connection Information.

[image]
You will see all the information including the IP (IPv4 and IPv6) of any device connected. In this case it is only showing one device since I have only one connected, but if I had multiple ones it would show each one on a different tab
[image]

Comment: What an ugly first screenshot. Maybe you have different subpixel layout or whatever, but on my screen this looks quite ugly (patchy greenish-yellow text).

Comment: @Ruslan yes, looks very broken somehow; And it seems to be redundant anyway?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel yeah, the follow-up text is a more full output.

Comment: It's the same output but i can't take a screenshot of the full output!

Comment: I remember that `ifconfig` is deprecated on Linux and serious Linux users/admins use `ip addr` instead.

Comment: Why do you get one IP using ifconfig and another IP using the GUI?

Comment: the screenshots are taken from different sources

Comment: @M.Tarun next time, prefer copy-n-paste for terminal output instead screenshots. Actually try to not use screenshots at all.

Answer (score 6):

`ifconfig` is and old command, that is still widely used, but if you are starting with network-related commands, you should use `ip` tool.
`ip a`, which is abbreviation for `ip addr` is what you are looking for in this particular case.

Check `ip` out, it really is better than `ifconfig` in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

These other answers are great, but here's a very simple alternative that doesn't spew out a mouthful of information:

```
host `hostname`
```

`hostname` returns your computer's name, and `host` resolves a hostname to an IP address.

Alternatively, you can just do:

```
hostname -I
```

Which does (from the man page):

> `-I`, `--all-ip-addresses`
>   Display  all  network addresses of the host. This option enumerates all configured addresses on  all  network  interfaces.  The loopback  interface  and  IPv6 link-local addresses are omitted. Contrary to option -i, this option does not depend on name resolution.  Do not make any assumptions about the order of the output.

Answer (score 2):

The command you are looking for is `ifconfig`.